# PHP Multi dimensional array sort with key

Tags: php, sorting, multidimensional-array, associative-array

I have an array like below

```
Array
(

[1236669] => Array
    (
        [banner_type] => OMAX
        [bannerid] => 1236669
        [zone_id] => 119789
        [zone_name] => OMAX-Supply - Mobile Web Tablet Interstitial
        [zone_manager_id] => 76
        [zone_manager_name] => Thumbtribe Manager
        [banner_name] => THUMBTRIBE_MW_TAB_Interstitial
        [banner_manager_id] => 288
        [banner_manager_name] => OMAX Manager
        [prev_day_req] => 0
    )
)
```

I want to sort the 2-D array on the basis of second level key , which means i want the array to be:

```
Array
(

[1236669] => Array
    (
        [banner_type] => OMAX
        [bannerid] => 1236669
        [banner_name] => THUMBTRIBE_MW_TAB_Interstitial
        [banner_manager_id] => 288
        [banner_manager_name] => OMAX Manager
        [prev_day_req] => 0
        [zone_id] => 119789
        [zone_name] => OMAX-Supply - Mobile Web Tablet Interstitial
        [zone_manager_id] => 76
        [zone_manager_name] => Thumbtribe Manager

    )
)
```

I tried asort, ksort, array_multisort but nothing working

Comment: `ksort($ar[1236669]);`

Answer (score 1):

You have to use ksort on each child of main array. like this...

```
<?php
$array =array ( 1236 => array
        (
            'banner_type' => 'OMAX',
            'bannerid' => 12369,
            'zone_id' => 1197,
            'zone_name' => 'OMAX-Supply - Mobile Web Tablet Interstitial',
            'zone_manager_id' => 76,

        )
    );

foreach ($array as $key => $arr){
    ksort($arr);
    $array[$key] = $arr;
}
echo '<pre>';
    print_r($array);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

A oneliner solution:

```
array_map(function ($item) { ksort($item); return $item; }, $input);
```

[array_map<sup>php</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) iterates over all of the associative arrays and sorts their keys with [ksort<sup>php</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php).

Answer (score -1):

please try this code dear
if your array like this than out put become like

```
     <?php
        $marks =  Array
(

1236669 => Array
    (
        'banner_type' => 'OMAX',
        'bannerid' => '1236669',
        'zone_id' => '119789',
        'zone_name' => 'OMAX-Supply - Mobile Web Tablet Interstitial',
        'zone_manager_id' => '76',
        'zone_manager_name' => 'Thumbtribe Manager',
        'banner_name' => 'THUMBTRIBE_MW_TAB_Interstitial',
        'banner_manager_id' => '288',
        'banner_manager_name' => 'OMAX Manager',
        'prev_day_req' => '0'
    )
);


ksort($marks);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($marks);
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

**output**

```
Array
(
      [1236669] => Array
      (
         [banner_type] => OMAX
         [bannerid] => 1236669
         [zone_id] => 119789
         [zone_name] => OMAX-Supply - Mobile Web Tablet Interstitial
         [zone_manager_id] => 76
         [zone_manager_name] => Thumbtribe Manager
         [banner_name] => THUMBTRIBE_MW_TAB_Interstitial
         [banner_manager_id] => 288
         [banner_manager_name] => OMAX Manager
         [prev_day_req] => 0
     )
 )
```

best of luck

Comment: i think your array's id or key not access ksort()  function properly